# Load HTML file from website instead of chrome extension in default popup box

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, google-chrome-extension

Currently we are loading HTML files in default popup box from Chrome extension directory but we need to load HTML files from my web server.

How can I do this?

Comment: What is "default popup box from chrome extension directory"?

Comment: No. You'll have to use an iframe in your popup.

Answer (score -1):

Of course you can. There's many web servers out there that you can try. Try MAMP server, install it on your computer, put your index.html in the MAMP/htdocs folder. There's ton of information on web server which you can install it on your local computer.

Comment: This answer is not related to the question.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, all browsers request to server. Server responses with files generally. Those files are rendered on the screen by browser.

You can go to developer tools from settings and then go to networks tab. All files will be there. Even dependencies as well.

I hope this is what you were asking.

Comment: Thanks all for your reply!, @wOxxOm, could you please provide me example or document for it?

Comment: This answer is completely unrelated to the question.